# Mean.IO +Grunt - Configure as unix service

Tags: node.js, express, centos, gruntjs

I have an Mean.io app (node.js, expresss, grunt);

All fine on my own machine, I run with grunt command at the app root.

I need to install it on a server (CentOS) someone can give a clue?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you using Supervisor.

I'm using following configuration:

```
[program:daemon]
command = /usr/local/bin/node server.js
user = server
directory = /home/server/mnt/
autostart = true
```

Eventually declare *NODE_MODULES* environment variable if you are using global modules.

PS. Some people are using node-forever but I'm fully satisfied with Supervisor.